# Wordpress - Broken Images

Tags: image, wordpress, filepath

I have a number of jpg files within the images folder of my custom themes that are linked to a template. I can't see what is wrong but the images are appearing broken. I can only imagine I have the file path wrong:

```
<img src="images/leads.jpg" width="176" height="58" alt="leads" />
```

Similarly, I am trying to link images dynamically to the custom fields set on the relevant WP back-end page and nothing is appearing. I am using the following code in the template:

```
 <img src='<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sales', true); ?>' />
```

I have tried to link this to to the page "images/sales.jpg" in the custom field.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the template_url first.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url').get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sales', true); ?>/images/lead.jpg" width="176" height="58" alt="leads" />
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I copied your link but the image is still broken.

Comment: Would you have a link to the page?

Comment: Sorry, the page is run locally. Would it help to see the code that WP is outputting?

Comment: Actually, it was only that I copied the link direct when I noticed the end part of the string contains 'leads' does not match to 'sales'.  Adjusted and all works fine now!!

Answer (score 0):

In your theme, all the paths must be refereed as absolute paths. Try:

```
<img src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sales', true); ?>' />
```

Comment: Thanks but link still broken.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<img src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() '.images/.' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sales', true); ?>' />
```